# over partition by without an aggregate function, avoiding group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, window-functions

**Is there any way in which I could use a window function like `over (partition by column)` without using it as an aggregate function?**

I have lots of columns and **I don't want to use group by** since I'll then have to specify both in the select and in the group by.

I am giving a syntax example, which needs somehow to be corrected (by you guys cause it's not working when I adapt it on my real query(real query is too long and time consuming to explain it so just go with an example)).

let's assume this works:

```
select *,
( select
sum (column1) over (partition by column2) as sumCol1
from myTable
where column20 = column21
)
from myTable
```

ok, now I want to do the same thing with two changes:

**1:** NO aggregate function

**2:** `column1` this time would be a `DATE` (I wouldn't be able to use an aggregate function with a `date` as far as I know, but as I am trying eliminate the aggregate, that shouldn't matter.)

What i want should be somehow like this (query not correct, since this is what i'm trying to achieve)

```
  select *,
    ( select
    column1 over (partition by column2) as Col1New
    from myTable
    where column20 = column21
    )
    from myTable
```

SQL Server 2012

Thanks

edit:

sample data:

```
     rN         rD          rnc      d     e   name  
    abc1m      2010-03-31   abc     5.7    2   blue   
    abc3m      2010-04-15   abc     5.7    3   blue  
    abc1y      2010-02-14   abc     5.7    4   blue   
    xfx1m      2010-02-31   xfx     1.7    2   blue  
    xfx3m      2010-03-24   xfx     1.7    1   blue  
    xfx1y      2012-03-30   xfx     1.7    1.7 red    <= d=e use this date for "red" rows
    tnt1m      2010-03-28   tnt     9.6    2   red   
    tnt3m      2010-01-12   tnt     9.6    9.6 blue   <= d=e use this date for "blue" rows
    tnt1y      2010-08-20   tnt     9.6    2   red
```

Expected table, please look at `expectedCol`

```
rN         rD          rnc      d     e   name  expectedCol
abc1m      2010-03-31   abc     5.7    2   blue  2010-01-12 
abc3m      2010-04-15   abc     5.7    3   blue  2010-01-12 
abc1y      2010-02-14   abc     5.7    4   blue  2010-01-12 
xfx1m      2010-02-31   xfx     1.7    2   blue  2010-01-12 
xfx3m      2010-03-24   xfx     1.7    1   blue  2010-01-12 
xfx1y      2012-03-30   xfx     1.7    1.7 red   2012-03-30 
tnt1m      2010-03-28   tnt     9.6    2   red   2012-03-30 
tnt3m      2010-01-12   tnt     9.6    9.6 blue  2010-01-12 
tnt1y      2010-08-20   tnt     9.6    2   red   2012-03-30
```

The logic is this: when d = e then look at rD and take that date and put it into expectedCol1 group by name

So, I would want to write soemthing like this:

```
select *,
(select rD over (partition by name) as expectedCol1
from myTable
where d = e)
from myTable
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desire output? That will help a lot.

Comment: You can always use aggregated function `MAX()`

Comment: do you actually need data sample to answer : `is it possible to use partition by without an aggregate function`?

Comment: `column1 this time would be a DATE`, so, previosuly you were using sum on column1, what do you want for this date?

Comment: yes @CM2K because your question isnt clear and not sure what you are trying to achive. I can try to guess. but probably will be wasting my time.

Comment: i don't want any `sum` for a date. First example is working, since I can't use a sum for a date. Desired output is not a `date`, I want to group by column2 where `column20 = column21`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza , ok, I will make a table as data sample. Will edit my answer asap

Comment: `is it possible to use partition by without an aggregate function?`, yes, you can use `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK`, `NTILE`

Comment: btw `I don't want to use group by` If you use `partition by` you dont need `group by`    this is valid  `SELECT id, SUM(sales) over (partition by ID) FROM SALES`

Comment: If you *know* that there'll only be a single value in each partition then, as Juan suggested, you can frequently use `MAX()` since if its only given a single input value, that's the same value it will return. If there are *multiple* values in a single partition, what output do you expect *without* using an aggregate?

Comment: please see my edited question

Comment: Looks like you could better get `expectedCol` with a CASE statement or a subquery.

Comment: Yes, and it certainly looks like putting `MAX(rD)` where you currently have `rD` would work, for the blue entries. Even with your sample, it's not clear how the red entries get their `expectedCol` values.

Comment: @TabAlleman the thing is, the real table is huge and lots of different values. I can't really write 'case when name is blue then ...when name is red then...`

Comment: You should also include your expected result.  Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Oh, so sorry, you are right. Made a small mistake in the table definition. Now should be clear, sorry again. Rushed the table a bit to offer a sample

Comment: Based on your example, you only have to write `CASE WHEN d=e THEN .. ELSE .. END`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the expected result is the column `expectedCol`

Comment: @CM2K what happen when `d <> e`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza , nothing since in `expectedCol` it is placed the value for the date when `d=e` and this can only occur once per name

Comment: @CM2K but in your sample show some date, and should be null

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Once again, the `expectedCol` takes the value from the row where `d = e` for every name. This `d = e` can happen only once per a set of `name`. The table should be as I defined it and not null in any field

Comment: Here's a big source of confusion.  You say you've posted sample data, but it contains `ExpectedCol`.   Yet it sounds like `ExpectedCol` doesn't exist in your data, but should be derived as a result of a query.   If you would modify your post to SEPARATELY show Sample Data, and Desired Query Results based on the sample data, I think that would clear up a lot of confusion.

Comment: @TabAlleman It will make it easier to read, will do it now

Comment: @CM2K I include a comment in your data. let us know if that is what you want.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza You got it. This is exactly what I wanted. I will have access to the server and will be able to test your solutions tomorrow. Thank you all for your answers and sorry if I didn't make myself clear from the start as I should have had. I hope it's clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate the `rD` for each `name` where `d = e`

```
WITH myDate AS ( 
      SELECT name, rD
      FROM YourTable
      WHERE d = e
)
SELECT
       t.*, m.rD as expectedCol           
FROM YourTable t
JOIN myDate m
  ON t.name = m.name
```

Comment: how is your query being able "to tell" apart by the name. This is not groupping in any way

Comment: I fix it. The question wasnt clear.

Comment: upon testing more, I found your solution to be the best. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From your sample data, something simpler like this looks like it should work:

```
select t1.*,t2.rD as expectedCol1
from myTable t1
inner join (select name,rD from myTable where e = d) t2
on t1.name = t2.name
```

Since you've stated that the e=d combination only occurs once for each name, the `t2` subquery should contain one row for each name. If some names may not have any rows where e=d, if you want them included, you should change to a `left join` and then consider what `expectedCol1` should be in that case.

Comment: your query seems to work in selecting the right date where `e = d`, However don't get what happens in the join because this makes `myTable` from 150k rows to have 3.8 million rows. Any idea?

Comment: i think i can solve this by placing a `distinct` in `inner join (select distinct name,rD from myTable where e = d) t2` . Thoughts?

Comment: You have my upvote but I had to change the "accepted answer" to the `cte` version from Juan since it works better and faster. But thanks, you stil gave me a good idea

Answer (score 1):

A third way to do this, as I mentioned in my comments, is with a simple sub-query:

```
SELECT t.*, (
  SELECT rD FROM myTable t2 WHERE t2.e=t2.d AND t2.Name=t.Name
) AS ExpectedCol
FROM myTable t
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, but i'm receiving the error: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: If you are getting that error, that means you are wrong when you say that there is only row per team that can have e=d.   The only way you would get that error is if there is a team with more than one such row.   If you correct your data, this will work.